# After .NET updates some client machines attempting to change cypher to TLS 1.0 when connecting to Web Service

Tags: .net, windows, tls1.2

We have a WPF application that connects to a web service.

We have seen two incidents so far where the connection fails after installing .NET updates (KB4522741 or KB4520405)

Using Wireshark it appears that the client machine is trying to renegotiate down to TLS v1.0 (it originally connects using 1.2)

This is a screenshot of Wireshark for a normal connection at line 69

[image: TLS Correct]

This is a screenshot at the same line number for the faulting apps

[image: TLS Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` to set the required TLS version in the client application.

Force it to TLS 1.2

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Or support TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.2

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :-)

Comment: Also - targeting .NET 4.6 that should connect initially using TLS v1.2, and has run flawlessly for the last couple of years until these recent .NET patches. It only seems to effect a small percentage of the user base

Comment: You can add it in the start up of you program. Since it's a static setting

Comment: That has done the job, it's now working. Thank you for your help :-) I have marked it up and as the answer.